# Accumulo tservers not starting on remote nodes

Tags: accumulo

I have setup an accumulo cluster on AWS where I have two machines `master` and `slave1`. The `master` node is intended to behave like both `monitor` and `tserver`. Here are my settings of accumulo.

this is my `conf/accumulo-site.xml`

```
  <property>
    <name>instance.volumes</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>comma separated list of URIs for volumes. example: hdfs://localhost:9000/accumulo</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>instance.zookeeper.host</name>
    <value>localhost:2181</value>
    <description>comma separated list of zookeeper servers</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>instance.secret</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
    <description>A secret unique to a given instance that all servers must know in order to communicate with one another.
      Change it before initialization. To
      change it later use ./bin/accumulo org.apache.accumulo.server.util.ChangeSecret --old [oldpasswd] --new [newpasswd],
      and then update this file.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.memory.maps.max</name>
    <value>256M</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.memory.maps.native.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.cache.data.size</name>
    <value>15M</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.cache.index.size</name>
    <value>40M</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>trace.token.property.password</name>
    <!-- change this to the root user's password, and/or change the user below -->
    <value>secret</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>trace.user</name>
    <value>root</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.sort.buffer.size</name>
    <value>50M</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>tserver.walog.max.size</name>
    <value>256M</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>general.classpaths</name>
    <value>
      <!-- Accumulo requirements -->
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-server.jar,
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-core.jar,
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-start.jar,
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-fate.jar,
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/accumulo-proxy.jar,
      $ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/[^.].*.jar,
      <!-- ZooKeeper requirements -->
      $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/zookeeper[^.].*.jar,
      <!-- Common Hadoop requirements -->
      $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
      <!-- Hadoop 2 requirements -->
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/[^.].*.jar,
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/(?!slf4j)[^.].*.jar,
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/[^.].*.jar,
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/[^.].*.jar,
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/[^.].*.jar,
      $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey.*.jar,
      </value>
    <description>Classpaths that accumulo checks for updates and class files.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

this is my `conf/masters`

```
localhost
```

this is my `conf/slaves`

```
localhost
slave1
```

My hadoop cluster is working perfectly fine and also, Zookeeper is running on master as well. The accumulo is initialize and I ran `start-all.sh` script which shows that it is starting tserver on slave1 but the web interface is only is only showing 1 tserver running which is `master:9997`.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I have written `localhost` for the zookeeper entry in `accumulo-site.xml` and hence the tservers couldn't find the zookeeper on remote node. I changed it and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Use fully-qualified domain names (hostnames) when referring to nodes. When you use `localhost`, how that resolves to a physical machine is dependent on what node you run Accumulo commands from.

For example, if you ran a `start-all.sh` from your "slave1" node, you would end up trying to start a TabletServer on `localhost` and `slave1` which would be the same node.

Even in the case where you happened to get the TabletServer started on `slave`, did you SSH to that host and check if a TabletServer process is running? Did you see if there is information in the .out/.err or .log files for the TabletServer? A common-initial setup issue is when users do not configure password-less SSH correctly (the user running Accumulo must be able to ssh to the given hostname from your `slaves` file e.g. `ssh slave1`).

Comment: I am able to ssh to the machines without passwords. Also, I tried adding names to the `etc/hosts` file and then used them in the accumulo master and slave files in conf directory, but it is the same.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me look for the real problem